# Sphinx thinks files were changed even though they weren't

Tags: pycharm, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using PyCharm to create a documentation project in Sphinx with restructuredtext, and starting yesterday every single build seems to think that a bunch of files were changed even though they weren't.

After a lot of trial and error, I was able to narrow down exactly which files it is affecting: any file that references, in its toctree, a file that was created after some point yesterday.

So essentially:

- Doc1.rst was created two days ago, and includes in its toctree Doc2.rst and Doc3.rst.
- Doc2.rst was created two days ago
- Doc3.rst was created yesterday afternoon

Doc1.rst will be considered "changed" in every build, even if I haven't changed a single character anywhere in the project, simply because it references Doc3.rst. Doc3 itself, not to mention Doc2, are not considered "changed".

Anybody know what's going on and how to fix it? I've tried clearing the output folder, deleting all three documents and recreating them, etc. No luck.

Thanks in advance for any advice or assistance you can provide.

EDIT: Upon further experimentation, the above definition of which files it affects does not seem to be as simple as I thought. I created a Doc4 that references Doc3 that is *not* stuck in this constantly-changed loop, but a Doc5 that references Doc3 that *is* stuck. So something more complicated is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

[Sphinx is using file modified time to check if it has changed](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/f45dc5e1398f7850e23003cac200ad3433da2a78/sphinx/environment/__init__.py#L383). You need to figure out

- If the file modification timestamp has changed
- What changes it on your file system

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm on Windows 10, and the file modification timestamps are accurate to the last time they were edited. I'm doing `.\make.bat html` twice in a row, and Sphinx is reprocessing these files both times, even though the "Date modified" field is three hours old. So something is clearly going wrong here...

Comment: Try setting Sphinx logging output to `DEBUG` level and see if it gives you any hint.

Comment: I had too much on plate to try that yesterday. Came into the office today, edited one document, built - and only that one document got edited. I stared at it, hit build again immediately, and nothing got built.

So apparently it fixed itself overnight when I wasn't looking? I hate it when that happens, but at least I don't need to worry about it (for now).

If it recurs I'll try to debug it as you suggested. Thank you for the help, and sorry that it ended up being irrelevant...